# mid()=foo in VBS?

Tags: vba, string

In VBA and VB6 I can assign something to `mid` for Example `mid(str,1,1)="A"` in VBS this doesn't work.
I need this because String concatenation is freakin' slow
Here is the actual code i hacked together real quick

```
Function fastXMLencode(str)
    Dim strlen
    strlen = Len(str)
    Dim buf
    Dim varptr
    Dim i
    Dim j
    Dim charlen
    varptr = 1
    buf = Space(strlen * 7)
    Dim char
    For i = 1 To strlen
        char = CStr(Asc(Mid(str, i, 1)))
        charlen = Len(char)
        Mid(buf, varptr, 2) = "&#"
        varptr = varptr + 2
        Mid(buf, varptr, charlen) = char
        varptr = varptr + charlen
        Mid(buf, varptr, 1) = ";"
        varptr = varptr + 1
    Next
    fastXMLencode = Trim(buf)
End Function
```

How can i get this to work in VBS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authoritative source explicitly stating it's not available in VBScript:

[Visual Basic for Applications Features Not In VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30593abb%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Strings: Fixed-length strings LSet, RSet **Mid Statement** StrConv

VBA has both a Mid *Statement* and a Mid *Function*.  VBScript only has the Mid Function.

<strike>The one other option you have if you are stuck doing this in VBScript is to **make API calls**.  Since you are already comfortable working directly with the string buffer this might not be too big a jump for you.  This page should get you started:  [String Functions](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/D369B2EB96EDF9550A45F7AAFAFBF5C3.html)</strike>

Sorry, it looks like API calls are out, too: [Rube Goldberg Memorial Scripting Page: Direct API Calls](http://www.mvps.org/scripting/rube/index.htm#Direct%20API%20Calls)  Unless you want to write an ActiveX wrapper for your calls, but we're starting to get into an awful lot of work (and additional maintenance requirements) now.

Comment: This article may also be of interest to you: [Why Strings Are Slow](http://www.angelfire.com/pq/jamesbarbetti/articles/strings/001_WhyStringsAreSlow.htm)

Comment: Sadly I'm stuck with VBS. I ended up just replacing a few characters that actually made problems, it fast enough now. I'll be fun again as soon as someone uses a new char i havent in the replace list

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. You will have to rebuild the string from scratch.

Comment: I'm accepting this in combination with mwolfe02's answer. I knew I couldn't do it with mid, but I hoped there was an alternative way to modify a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, `mid(str,1,1)` is a function which just returns a number (str is not passed 'by reference' and is not altered).

Comment: I know it makes no sense, but seriously, you can do that, at least with VBA, try to run it in excel.

Answer (score 0):

It's never too late to suggest an answer, even to a decade-old question...

One great thing about VBScript is that even though it's a subset of VB/VBA it still lets you declare (and use) classes. And having classes implies them having properties, with getters and/or *setters*... if you can guess where I'm going...

So if you wrap a class around a VBA-compatible implementation of `Mid()`, it's actually possible to emulate Mid() statements with a Let property. Consider the following code:

```
Class CVBACompat
    ' VB6/VBA-Like Mid() Statement
    Public Property Let LetMid(ByRef Expression, ByVal StartPos, ByVal Length, ByRef NewValue) ' ( As String, As Long, As Long, As String)
        Dim sInsert ' As String
        sInsert = Mid(NewValue, 1, Length)
        Expression = Mid(Expression, 1, StartPos - 1) & sInsert & Mid(Expression, StartPos + Len(sInsert))
    End Property
    
    ' VB6/VBA-Like IIf() Function
    Public Function IIf(Expression, TruePart, FalsePart)
        If CBool(Expression) Then
            IIf = TruePart
        Else
            IIf = FalsePart
        End If
    End Function
End Class: Public VBACompat: Set VBACompat = New CVBACompat: Public Function IIf(X, Y, Z): IIf = VBACompat.IIf(X, Y, Z): End Function
```

[VBA's language specification](https://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-VBAL/%5BMS-VBAL%5D.pdf#page=91) says that when `Mid( <string-expression>, <start> [, <length> ] )` is used as a statement, what's to be replaced in the source string `<string-expression>` is the lowest number of characters given the entire RHS expression *or* as limited by the `<lenght>` argument, when *provided*. Now, you can't have optional arguments in VBScript, so if you want to be able to also use statements of the sort `Mid( <string-expression>, <start> ) = <expression>` you'll have to have two separate implementations.

The implementation proposed above can be checked with the following code (not including checks for error-throwing conditions, which are the same as for the `Mid()` function anyway) :

```
Dim f ' As String
Dim g ' As String

    f = "1234567890"
    g = f
    
    ' VB6 / VBA: Mid(f, 5, 2) = "abc"
    VBACompat.LetMid(f, 5, 2) = "abc"
    ' VB6 / VBA: Mid(g, 5, 4) = "abc"
    VBACompat.LetMid(g, 5, 4) = "abc"
    
    WScript.Echo "First call " & IIf(f = "1234ab7890", "passes", "fails")
    WScript.Echo "Second call " & IIf(g = "1234abc890", "passes", "fails")
```

In any case, since the proposed solution is just an emulation of otherwise native code implementations (in VB6, VBA), and still implies string concatenation anyway with the overhead of class instantiation + VTable translations, the OP'd be better off creating and making available an ActiveX component (OCX) to do concatenations in series.